# Gradle JRE vs JDK please add lib/tools.jar from your JDK

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, powermock

I'm running java tests with gradle.
here is the exception I have:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load Java agent; please add lib/tools.jar from your JDK to the classpath
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassRedefiner.redefine(PowerMockClassRedefiner.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.support.PowerMockAgentTestInitializer.redefine(PowerMockAgentTestInitializer.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.support.PowerMockAgentTestInitializer.initialize(PowerMockAgentTestInitializer.java:41)
at com.blablacompany.app.weight.WeightMilestonesViewBeanUnitTest.setUpMock(WeightMilestonesViewBeanUnitTest.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load Java agent; please add lib/tools.jar from your JDK to the classpath
at org.powermock.modules.agent.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:70)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:40)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockAgent.verifyInitialization(PowerMockAgent.java:83)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockAgent.instrumentation(PowerMockAgent.java:76)
at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockClassRedefiner.redefine(PowerMockClassRedefiner.java:57)
... 37 more
```

It turns out that for some reason my gradle uses JRE's folder as java.home and this is why it can not find the tools.jar. 
I on't think that I want manually add it to my classpath though. I'm wondering if there any way to tell gradle to use JDK's java home instead of JRE's? 
I also tried overriding it using org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties file and it did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

WHen I run the same tests from my IDE(Intellij IDEA) all tests are passed successfully. I'm running all it on Mac OS.

```
println System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
println System.properties['java.home']
```

displays:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home                                                                                                                                                                
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Comment: What does the following print when you add it to the build script? `println System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` Which OS/JDK?

Comment: Updated the question:
println System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") -->> prints 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home. 
   
println System.properties['java.home'] -->> prints                                                                                                                                                             
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, seems that JRE is actually the right one that I need to use. No reason java.home to be set to JDK.
 So the way I solved it was just adding tools library to my classpath:

```
testCompile ([fileTree(dir: "${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib", include: '*tools.jar'),fileTree(dir: "lib/test", include: '*.jar') ])
```

Initially the reason why I did not wanted to do this was that once I added it I had a bunch of

```
java 7 errors: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 10
```

I did fix it by adding "-noverify" parameter to my tests closure:

```
Closure basicTestConfiguration = {
jvmArgs "-Dactivemq.directory=${testActivemqDir}",
        "-Duser.timezone=Etc/UTC",
        "-javaagent:${configurations.testAgent.singleFile}",
        "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m",
        "-noverify"
...
}
```

and applying this closure to my test suite:

```
postCommitSuite basicTestConfiguration
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not a JDK vs. JRE problem. The values of `JAVA_HOME` vs. `java.home` are correct and expected (see other SO question on this topic). `tools.jar` is necessary to *execute* tools such as `javac` and `javadoc`. However, neither the JDK's `javac` command line compiler nor Gradle's `JavaCompile` task will automatically put `tools.jar` on the compile class path of user code. Instead you'll have to add it explicitly. For example:

```
def jdkHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")

dependencies {
    compile files("$jdkHome/lib/tools.jar")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. In [a comment on GRADLE-1477](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1477?focusedCommentId=14816&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14816) you recommended the following:

```dependencies {
  compile files("${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/tools.jar")
}```

which seems simpler, safer and more portable. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Edited

Check this out http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html.
Especially this section

> The configuration is applied in following order (in case an option is configured in multiple locations the last one wins):
>
> from gradle.properties located in project build dir.
>
> from gradle.properties located in gradle user home.
>
> from system properties, e.g. when -Dsome.property is used in the command line.

Comment: I think I did, since System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") prints this to console: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home, which is correct JDK path on my MAC.