# gradle version x is required try editing distributionurl

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

getting this after downloading gradle 2.10 with android studio 1.5.1. when running gradle form the command line. gradlew complains about not finding tools.jar.

changing the plugin to: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' (from 1.3.1) makes gradle iD work. gradlew iD still fails with not finding tools.jar.

how do i fix the tools.jar problem?

is there an easy/proper way to get the wrapper to use the 2.10 version?

edit: solved the tools.jar problem (was using jdk1.9.0) but that has intoduced a bunch of: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
>   xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe''

edit: got those to go away by removing the: compile files("${jdkHome}/lib/tools.jar") dependency. so what worked was to switch from jdk 1.9 to jdk 1.8.

Comment: How did you switch to 2.10? Can you post the exact error message you're seeing please.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23973537/745574

Comment: i downloaded 2.10 and added it to my classpath. then changed  the plugin to: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar

Comment: foo, no tools.jar in jdk1.9.0 :(

Comment: now jdk1.8.0_60 is failing with: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:  - stay tuned.

Comment: see edit - had to remove the compile files("${jdkHome}/lib/tools.jar") dependency no that i switched back to jdk 1.8